# Adding Tomcat Server in Intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

There are many questions on this website regarding  that please be assured that I have checked them and didn't find my answer.

I am really a newbie in IntelliJ. Here is my edit configuration screenshot. Please help me with adding tomcat server in this IDE, I know how to do it in Eclipse but Intellij is giving me hard time.

[image]

Comment: Have you got the Tomcat plugin enabled?

Comment: they don't it is not in the list. Have you got communtiry edition - you need the full version.

Comment: See below for details on how to use a tomcat plugin to let basic operation work with Community Edition.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tomcat integration is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, while you are running the Community Edition. [Here is the page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) that describes the difference between the editions.

Comment: thank you.. that is what I thought. I can't buy it though. But yeah using the ultimate version evaluation mode.

Comment: @dharam -- see jimhawkins answer below for integration with tomcat from IDEA community edition.

Answer (score 6):

Did you think of using maven? If you do so, you can use the "tomcat7-maven-plugin" and its goals "deploy" and "undeploy".

Here's an example pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.example</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>dm-p0-servlet</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>tomcat7-local</server>
                    <path>/miniservlet</path>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean-undeploy</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-deploy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The element `<server>tomcat7-local</server>` refers to the `<servers>`  section in `~/.m2/settings.xml`, where the credentials for the Tomcat server authentication are stored:

```xml
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>tomcat7-local</id>
            <username>adminScript</username>
            <password>geheim</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
```

The username "adminScript" and its password are defined in `<Tomcat-Home>/conf/tomcat-users.xml` .

Comment: Thank you!  One suggestion: in execution > goals > goal I used `redeploy` rather than `deploy`.  In this case if the package is not already deployed, it detects it's not there and continues; otherwise just knows to ... redeploy :-)

Comment: Hi Jim, shall you note the downside of going the maven way is that it does not support Hot swap feature. Perhaps few folks would like to see Incubation admission for the mvp in that field of interest !